# How to fix error inserting into linked list. from file stream

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to insert values into a linked list, but keep having the program crash on me. I know I'm doing something wrong I'm just not sure what and after spending 8 hrs trying different methods, I'm ready to ask for help.

I've tried many different ways to get this to work. Sometimes I seem to be able to get the nodes stored and connected, but then when I try to print, it will either only print the first node or print nothing at all.

```
typedef struct histogram {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct histogram *next;
} List;

static List *createWord(char word[]) {
    char *wordPtr = word;

    List *node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    node->word = wordPtr;
    node->count = 1;
    return node;
} 

static void insertAtTail(List **head, List *node) {
    List *previous = *head;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = node;
    } else {
        while (previous->next != NULL) { // error location
            previous = previous->next;
        }
        previous->next = node;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
}

void readMain(char *fileName) {
    // responsible for read operatons and list storage.
    // Counts total words and uniques than stores words in linked list.

    char word[100];
    char *wordArray[1500] = { NULL };

    static int noOfWords = 0;
    static int uniqueWords = 0;

    List *head = NULL;
    List *temp = NULL;

    fileRead(inputFile);

    while (fscanf(inputFile, "%s", word) == 1) {
        if (determineIfWord(word) == 0) {
            noOfWords++;
            temp = createWord(word);
            insertAtTail(&head, temp); // error occurs here

            if (!compareWords(wordArray, word, uniqueWords)) {
                wordArray[uniqueWords] = calloc(strlen(word) + 1,
                                                sizeof(char));

                if (wordArray[uniqueWords] == NULL) {
                    printf("calloc failed to allocate memory\n");
                    exit(0);
                }
                strcpy(wordArray[uniqueWords], word);
                uniqueWords++; 
            }
        }

    fclose(inputFile);

    freeArray(wordArray, uniqueWords);

    noOfWords -= 1;
    printf("\n%s processed: %i unique words found.\n\n", fileName, uniqueWords);
}
```

I need the nodes to be stored and linked together allowing me to access the linked list.

Comment: You seem to be missing a } somewhere in insertAtTail. Can you double check and edit?

Comment: A node is not a list, a list is not a node. Inserting at the end of a singly linked list without a pointer to the tail is fubar. The member `next` of your structure returned from `createWord()` is uninitialized. Stopped reading at *`fscanf(inputFile, "%s", word)`*

Comment: `previous->next = node;` is wrong when `if (*head == NULL)` is True. Because `previous = *head` which means `previous` is NULL

Comment: @MFisherKDX Copy&paste error. previous->next = node, should be within the else statement. Fixing now.

Comment: Ok. But now `node->next` is not set to NULL when `if (*head == NULL)` is True. Neither is it initialized to NULL in `createWord`. So after adding the first element to the list, it's not terminated with NULL and the list is screwed up.

Comment: @Swordfish I know a node is not a list, it is written like that for convenience sake for later on in the programs development. Regardless, that's irrelevant. `next` is meant to be uninitialised as it's value is assigned later, you'd know that if you read the entire code before giving your opinion. You're response is both ignorant and arrogant.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Does that matter? I thought if it was uninitialised it would be considered NULL?

Comment: Actually. @Swordfish is right on the mark. It's not easy to follow this question because you have edited the code three times now. But at the current edit, the `node->next` is indeed uninitialized and will cause a problem exactly where you've commented. Also, there is a very good reason to think about a better way to add to the end. Adding to the end this way (traversing to get there) is not necessarily wrong. It's just dumb.

Comment: No. In C if a variables is uninitialized, then it can be anything. It might be NULL. It might not be. You must explicitly initialize your pointer to NULL

Comment: @MFisherKDX The edits have been minor and not really effected the overall structure, sorry if that was not obvious. As for the implementation, if you couldn't tell I'm trying to figure things out as I go, I'm not familiar with C. I didn't know that with uninitialised variables.

Comment: @MFisherKDX @Swordfish You were right about `next` being uninitialised. I thought an uninitialised variable was NULL but clearly I was wrong. The problem has been fixed now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems in the code:

- the header files are missing. You need at least `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>`
- There is a missing `}` before the `fclose(inputFile);`.
- The function `createWord` should allocate a copy of the word, otherwise all nodes point to the same array in `main()`, where `fscanf()` writes the last word read from the file.
- you should protect against buffer overflow by telling `fscanf()` the maximum number of characters to store to the destination array: `fscanf(inputFile, "%99s", word)`

Here is a modified version of `createWord`:

```c
static List *createWord(const char *word) {
    List *node = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (node) {
        node->word = strdup(wordPtr);
        node->count = 1;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned from the beginning that this is a snippet of the program and not the entire thing. The program compiles, so header files and brackets are all there. The char array is temp storage which is continuously overwritten when a value from the stream meets a certain criteria. If it met the criteria, the value of the char array will be stored in a node, before the value is replaced with another value that fits that criteria. This repeats until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: @Aevitas: OK, but we cannot see what you do not post. Some errors are just caused by missing header files. You call `createWord` for each word read by `fscanf()`, you **must** make a copy of the array for the node string otherwise all nodes point to the same array and therefore have the same string, namely the last ont read by `fscanf()`.

Comment: The program covers multiple classes so I only included what was relevant. You'll see some calls to functions that are not in the code I've shown. You're right all arrays having the last char array read by `fscanf()` causes all nodes to have that char arrays value. But, What exactly do you mean by "make a copy"  Do I simply do as you have done above and assign it as a constant?

Comment: `createWord` receives a pointer to the array `word` defined in `main`. You must allocate a new array of size `strlen(word) + 1`, copy the string to it and store this pointer in your new node. `strdup()` does the allocation and copy in one call.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much. You've helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You write way too complicated code.

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRING(x)

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

typedef struct node_tag {
    char *data;
    struct node_tag *next;
} node_t;

node_t* node_create(char const *word)
{
    node_t *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
    if (!new_node)
        return NULL;

    new_node->data = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    if (!new_node->data) {
        free(new_node);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(new_node->data, word);
    return new_node;
}

void node_free(node_t *node)
{
    assert(node && node->data);

    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}

node_t* node_advance(node_t *node)
{
    assert(node);
    return node->next;
}

typedef struct list_tag {
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
    size_t length;
} list_t;

list_t list_create(void)
{
    list_t list = { NULL, NULL, 0 };
    return list;
}

void list_free(list_t *list)
{
    assert(list);

    for (node_t *current_node = list->head; current_node;) {
        node_t *next_node = node_advance(current_node);
        node_free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;       
    }
}

bool list_append(list_t *list, char const *word)
{
    assert(list && word);

    node_t *new_node = node_create(word);
    if (!new_node) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!list->tail) {
        list->head = list->tail = new_node;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = node_create(word);
        list->tail = list->tail->next;
    }

    ++(list->length);
    return true;
}

bool list_contains(list_t *list, char const *word)
{
    assert(list && word);

    for (node_t *current_node = list->head; current_node; current_node = node_advance(current_node)) {
        if (strcmp(current_node->data, word) == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void list_print(list_t *list)
{
    assert(list);

    for (node_t *current_node = list->head; current_node; current_node = node_advance(current_node)) {
        puts(current_node->data);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t unique_words = 0;
    list_t words_list = list_create();

    for (char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1]; fscanf(input, "%" STRINGIFY(BUFFER_SIZE) "s", buffer) == 1;) {
        if (!list_contains(&words_list, buffer))
            ++unique_words;

        if (!list_append(&words_list, buffer)) {
            fclose(input);
            list_free(&words_list);
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }       
    }

    puts("Words found:");
    list_print(&words_list);
    printf("\nNumber of unique words: %zu\n\n", unique_words);

    fclose(input);
    list_free(&words_list);
}
```

Comment: I don't need a rewrite, this wouldn't work anyway as I only included the relevant code, the program covers multiple classes. The error was that I thought an uninitialised variable was considered NULL, which has been pointed out and I have now corrected. BTW if you're going to criticise what I've done please explain why it is wrong and suggest how I could correct it, what you've done is simply patronizing and not at all helpful.

Comment: @Aevitas *BTW if you're going to criticise what I've done please explain why it is wrong and suggest how I could correct it* – There is nothing wrong with your code. Well, technically. It's just horrible to read and maintain. If you don't see the difference in style in your and my approach then i can't help you. The key point is object oriented design.

Comment: Okay buddy, I suggest you stay away from any type of teaching position.

Comment: Wow -- never look a gift-horse in the mouth. And I guess we should add -- no good deed goes unpunished...